# Laravel population drop down box from multiple tables in a single view

Tags: database, laravel, multiple-tables, singlepage, population

I want to populate drop down box with data from two database tables in a single view.

So, I have two drop down boxes and I want to populate with data from two tables in order to select two different data.

CarsController.php code:

```
public function getCarList()
{
    $carsList = Car::all();
    return view('adminlte::books', compact('carsList'));
}
```

ClientsController.php code:

```
public function getClientList()
 {
    $clientsList = Client::all();
    return view('adminlte::books', compact('clientsList'));
 }
```

book.blade.php code:

```
<select name="color" id="clientName" class="form-control clientname">
   <option value="0" diabled="true" selected="true">-Select-</option>
   @foreach($clientsList as $cli)
       <option value="{{$cli->id}}">{{$cli->name}}</option>
   @endforeach

 </select>

 <select name="color" id="carName" class="form-control carname">
    <option value="0" diabled="true" selected="true">-Select-</option>
    @foreach($carsList as $carli)
       <option value="{{$carli->id}}">{{$carli->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
```

When I remove one of these select boxes in view, it works good, but together they don't work.

Comment: Because you call either getCarList method or getClientList method. So in each case you miss one variable. For example if you call getCarList you only pass $carLists to the view and when you call getClientList you only pass $clientsList variable to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both selects have name color ? Shouldn't it be car and client?

Comment: I've changed the name, but it doesn't work. It doesn't meter because in this case the name of selects are not used.
Error message is: 
Undefined variable: clientsList (View: /resources/views/vendor/adminlte/books.blade.php)

Comment: Oh I get it. Depending on the controller you want to show appropriate select but when hitting one controller, you don&#39;t have data from the other. Weird but if you need it, you have to check whether each value exists before you use it. For example @if($clientsList) and inside show select.

If you want both at the same time, you have to make 1 method which fetches both cars and clients and pass those to the view.

Comment: I've just change the return in ClientController like this:
public function getClientList()
    {
        $clientsList = Client::all();
        $carsList = Car::all();
        return view('adminlte::books', ['clientsList' => $clientsList, 'carsList' => $carsList]);

    }

and it works now. Thank you very much.